# Write Specified text from Doc to a Data frame

Tags: python, python-docx

I have to pick some specific text from a document and write to dataframe using Python.

I have tried the below code, where I can print all the columns from the document. Can anyone advise on how to pick and paste the required text to dataframe.

```py
doc = docx.Document('\\Location of input file.docx')
```

```py
result = [p.text for p in doc.paragraphs]
```

Comment: What is the required text? What did you try and where did you run into problems?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It would help if you included a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we could better diagnose what's going on

Comment: from a word document, i want to pick few text e.g. Name/ Roll number/ Certificate Number, Marks and write them in a data frame. I tried above code to input the word file, but need your support on step how i can pick these text.